# Using multiple Actions in Action<object> list

Tags: c#, action, icommand

I'm learning a bit more about using the `ICommand` interface and how to execute commands through the `RelayCommand` class I created.

Firstly, I did some research on what I am trying to achieve, but I can't find anything to help me or I do not really know how to search for what I am trying to do. Also, my knowledge of C# theory isn't really good so that's also not in my favour.

Basically I'm trying to send multiple actions through to my `RelayCommand` constructor and then iterate through all of the actions in the `List<Action<object>>` collection and execute them one by one. Here is my code:

*RelayCommand class constructor*

```
public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, List<Action<object>> actions)
{
    _canExecute = canExecute;

    foreach (var action in actions)
        _execute = action;
}
```

And then my command property inside my ***ViewModel***

```
private ICommand _updateExternals;
public ICommand UpdateExternals
{
    get
    {
        if (_updateExternals == null)
        {
            _updateExternals = new RelayCommand(
                x => CanExecute,
                Updater.UpdateExternals(this));//Here is where I am stuck
        }
        return _updateExternals;
    }
}
```

I know, from other examples, that if I only need to pass through a single `Action` instead of a list of Actions that the code would look like the following: `x => Updater.UpdateExternals(this));` and it would work, but as soon as I have a list of Actions as a parameter I get stuck.

So, if you haven't already guessed, my question is: How can I send through multiple Actions to my RelayCommand class?

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is my full RelayCommand class to give more of an idea of what I am doing.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, List<Action<object>> actions)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        foreach (var action in actions)
            _execute = action;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is a `Predicate<object>` (similar to `Func<object, bool>`) called `canExecute`? Iterating through the `actions` and assigning each of them (without invoking them) to the same field, which is what you do with `foreach (var action in actions)
        _execute = action;`, does not seem useful? I do not understand much of what you do.

Comment: How Updater.UpdateExternals looks like?

Comment: Simply loop your elements in the list and call the delegate: `foreach(a in myList) a(myParams);` But why do you overweite the `_execute`-field on every iteration within your `RelayCommand`-constructor?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for the comment Jeppe. I've edited my question so that it might explain a bit more of what I am doing.

Comment: @Evk It could be any method that I am trying to call. I have edited my question, so it could help to understand more of what I am trying to do. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve your problem, use `params` in constructor:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand {
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object>[] _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, params Action<object>[] actions) {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = actions;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        foreach (var action in _execute)
            action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then you can create such command as usual:

```
_updateExternals = new RelayCommand(
    x => CanExecute,
    x => Updater.UpdateExternals(this));//Here is where I am stuck
```

When you need to pass multiple actions:

```
_updateExternals = new RelayCommand(
    x => CanExecute,
    x => Updater.UpdateExternals(this),
    x => Updater.DoSomethingElse(this));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to have a list of the actions you want to execute, so add that as a field in your class and then set it in the constructor.
Then in your Execute method (interface implementation) you just iterate over the actions and call them one after another.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private List<Action<object>> _executes;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, List<Action<object>> actions)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _executes = actions;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        foreach(e in _executes )
        {            
           e(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

What you original code was doing was assigning the single action reference over and over with each of the actions from the constructor parameter so your class would only have executed the last action in the list when `Execute` is called.

Remember an `Action` and `Action<T>` is more or less just a reference to some method, named or anonymous (lambda).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sindri. I just have to mention that my issue at the moment isn't in my `RelayCommand` class, but with the coding in my `ViewModel`.

Comment: Ah yes you must wrap your multiple actions in a list, like this `new List<Action<object>>(){ commaSeparatedActionReferencesWithOutParenthesis }`

Comment: Instead of a `List<>` you can also use delegate combination. For example `public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, List<Action<object>> actions)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
foreach (var a in actions) { _multiExecute += a; }
    }` Note that `Action<>`, like any other .NET delegate type, supports "multicast" delegate instances.

Comment: The other answer @Evk will work too, as [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) means that it can take any number of parameters of the same type separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the single action reference in your answer @SindriJóelsson. It helped me a bit more to understand what I was doing wrong.